# Windows VS Code (User) installed in Program Files

Tags: visual-studio-code

Some time back I was prompted to move from the System-wide VS Code to the VS Code User installer.  I made the change but I find that the install is in the Program Files directory. This causes a problem when it checks for updates.  I constantly get an error dialog saying:

```
An error occurred while trying to create a file in the destination directory:
Access is denied.
```

This is annoying.  I am not sure why it installed into the Program Files directory.  Everything I have read says it should automatically install in the \Users directory.

I can try uninstalling and reinstalling but I don't really want to go through the hassle of figuring out (again) which extensions to add if I don't have to.  Plus, I don't have any confidence that a reinstall will have any different effects.

Are there any alternatives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can uninstall it and then use the portable archive version of VSCode.

See the [Download page](https://code.visualstudio.com/download) and click on `.zip 64 bits`.

Once uncompressed anywhere you want, that version of VSCode will be able to update itself without issue.

Comment: Before your answer I went ahead and bit the bullet and did a complete uninstall and reinstall with the latest installer.  This time it installed in the Users directory without any issue.  I'm still not sure what happened last time.  Anyway I didn't lose my installed extensions in the uninstall.